# ctx.cookies.set() vs setCookies in Deno std

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies, deno, oak

I'm currently working with Deno (Oak framework), and wanted to know what is the difference between using Oak's `ctx.cookies` (https://github.com/oakserver/oak/blob/main/cookies.ts) vs something from Deno's std lib (`setCookies`, `getCookie`, and `deleteCookie` from https://deno.land/std@0.120.0/http/cookie.ts).

Even though the Oak framework provides methods to work with cookies, what are the pros/cons to consider between the two? IS there ever a reason to use the std lib over oak's methods even when using the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: **if you're using Oak, use the methods provided by Oak** unless you have a specific reason not to. (It will be evident if you ever encounter such a scenario.)

---

The [`setCookie`](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/0.120.0/http/cookie.ts#L191-L199) function from `deno.land/std/http` simply appends a new `Set-Cookie` header to an existing [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) object. You *can* use this with Oak:

```ts
const cookie = {name: 'cookie_name' value: 'cookie_value'};
setCookie(ctx.response.headers, cookie);
```

The [`set`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/blob/v10.1.0/cookies.ts#L284-L329) method on `ctx.cookies` (which is an instance of the [`Cookies`](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/blob/v10.1.0/cookies.ts#L150-L363) class) from `deno.land/x/oak` allows you to operate directly on the cookies in the current request-response `context`:

```ts
await ctx.cookies.set('cookie_name', 'cookie_value');
```

When using it, you don't need to manually pass a reference to an existing `Headers` object (because it's already part of the context response object). This kind of higher-level abstraction means you don't have to manage (or necessarily even think about) as many discrete parts. Oak provides additional abstractions when working with cookies, such as [cryptographic signatures](https://github.com/oakserver/oak/tree/v10.1.0/#cookies). The documentation covers the details.

Comment: thanks jsejcksn! This helps